# Scanner is not reading the whole sentence sentence

Tags: java

Scanner is not reading the whole sentence. Or let's say I'm writing a method which reverses the words in a sentence while keeping them in their order in a sentence.

```
public static String reverse(String s) 
{
    String revStr = "";  
    for (int a = s.length()-1; a >= 0 ; a--)
    {
        revStr = revStr + s.charAt(a);
    }
    return revStr;    
}
```

My scanner:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = scan.next();
```

But when I write a sentence it reverses the first word and stops.

Comment: You need a loop in which you read words. I suggest using `nextLine()` to read the entire line at once and then splitting based on `\\s+` and then reversing the words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use nextline() function instead of next() to capture the whole line
Change `String s= scanner.nextLine();` instead of `String s= scanner.next();`

Answer (score 4):

You use `scan.next()`. This reads until whitespace (or whatever delimiter you set earlier, which you haven't). The default delimiter is whitespace.

Use `scan.nextLine()` to read an entire line of text (i.e. until you press enter).

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()):

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. [...]

You can change the delimiter by using `useDelimiter`

```
public Scanner useDelimiter(Pattern pattern)
```

> Sets this scanner's delimiting pattern to the specified pattern.